# How do I repeat a function that has different size inputs?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2019

Is there a single function that can multiply cell A1 by B1:B24 and put the results in C1:C24, then A2 by B1:B24 and put the results in C25:C48, then A3 by B1:B24 and put the results in C49:C72, etc... using a single formula that can be dragged down column C starting from C1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You may use this formula in C1:***

**::Caveat::**

- Since you have not mentioned that what version of Excel you are using
  so that I've suggested formula will work for all versions.
- If using Excel 365 then **edit** the post, I'll suggest a formula will automate this & will avoid drag the formula down.

---

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$3, CEILING(ROW(C1)/24, 1)) * INDEX($B$1:$B$24, MOD(ROW(C1)-1, 24) + 1)
```

---

**N.B.**

- Currently in Column A I've only 3 values in A1:A3 ,, you may add
  more.
- Insert the formula in C1 and then fill it down till required.
- Adjust cell references & total numbers of rows i.e. **24** ,, as needed.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was searching for.

Comment: @Jgh21 ,, that's nice it's working for you ,,, in case if U need Command especially for Higher Version like Excel 365 ,,,, please drop your need through comments ,,, then I'll edit the post & add  it ☺